# Why can't I import the 'math' library when embedding python in c?

Tags: c++, python, c

I'm using the example in python's 2.6 docs to begin a foray into embedding some python in C.  The [example C-code](http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html#pure-embedding) does not allow me to execute the following 1 line script:

```
import math
```

Using line:

```
./tmp.exe tmp foo bar
```

it complains

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rbroger1/scripts/tmp.py", line 1, in <module>
    import math
ImportError: [...]/python/2.6.2/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/math.so: undefined symbol: PyInt_FromLong
```

When I do `nm` on my generated binary (tmp.exe) it shows

```
0000000000420d30 T PyInt_FromLong
```

The function seems to be defined, so why can't the shared object find the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using Python 2.6, and I successfully compiled and ran that same example code that you listed, without changing anything in the source.

```
$ gcc python.c -I/usr/include/python2.6/ /usr/lib/libpython2.6.so
$ ./a.out random randint 1 100
Result of call: 39
$ ./a.out random randint 1 100
Result of call: 57
```

I specifically chose the `random` module because it does have `from math import log,...` so it is certainly importing the `math` module as well.

Your issue is probably due to how you're linking; see [this forum post](http://objectmix.com/python/311970-weird-embedding-problem.html) for a similar issue someone else had.  I can't find the links again, but it seems like there are some common issues when trying to link against Python's static library then importing modules that require a dynamic library.

Comment: To follow on from this, you are almost certainly not linking against the Python library correctly.  The dynamic linker is trying to resolve that symbol and can't find it in any of your linked libraries.  Static linkage quite often doesn't leave the symbols in place for the dynamic linker to resolve so in this case it's best to link dynamically.

Comment: Can I impose upon you two to answer the sequel to this question?  Unfortunately, my python install seems incomplete and I don't have libpython2.6.so

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472828/how-can-i-link-against-libpython-a-such-that-later-the-runtime-linker-can-find-al