# How can I link against libpython.a such that the runtime linker can find all the symbols in libpython.a?

Tags: python, gcc, g++

In a sequel question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469370/why-cant-i-import-the-math-library-when-embedding-python-in-c), my corporate environment lacks the `libpython2.6.so` shared object but has the `libpython2.6.a` file.  Is there a way that I can compile in `libpython2.6.a` while retaining the symbols in `libpython2.6.a` such that dynamic libraries can find these symbols at runtime?

My current compile with the static library looks like:

```
g++ -I/usr/CORP/pkgs/python/2.6.2/include/python2.6 \
    ~/tmp.cpp -pthread -lm -ldl -lutil \
    /usr/CORP/pkgs/python/2.6.2/lib/python2.6/config/libpython2.6.a \
    -o tmp.exe
```

However, if I load a module like 'math', it dies with:

```
undefined symbol: PyInt_FromLong
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass `--export-dynamic` to the linker. So from `g++` it's...

```
g++ -Wl,--export-dynamic ...
```

Comment: Note that passing `-rdynamic` is equivalent to passing `-Wl,--export-dynamic` https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html